# Handling psycopg2 errors properly

Tags: python, error-handling, django-rest-framework, psycopg2, try-except

I am building a web application that works as Web API server for our mobile and Electron app. I am trying to properly design our error handling too.

I use `Django`, `Django Rest Framework` for `RESTful API` implementation.

For `psycopg2 errors`, I get the following:

> "column "unifiedidd" of relation "basicinformation" does not
> exist\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO profile.basicinformation (unifiedidd,
> firstname,...\n                                              ^\nQUERY:
> INSERT INTO profile.basicinformation (unifiedidd, firstname,
> middlename, familyname, sex, birthdate) VALUES
> ('8f38f402-ddee-11ea-bfee-ead0fcb69cd9'::uuid, 'Lily Francis Jane',
> 'Luo Yi', 'Chao Fan', 'Male', '1990-03-20')\nCONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL
> function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement\n"

In my view file, I am catching these errors as such:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
 try:
  return Response({"message": "Cool"},status=http_200_OK)
 except ProgrammingError as e:
  return Response({"message": str(e)},status=http_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
 except IntegrityError as e:
  return Response({"message": str(e)},status=http_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
 except Exception as e:
  return Response({"message": str(e)},status=http_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

1. First thing I wanna confirm is, because of the content of the error, I assume it is not a good idea to output the whole thing right? Since it shows the actual query. This is useful but maybe for error logging for developer use only.
2. So I assume I need to output a custom message. But given that there are tons of errors that may be encountered and I think it's impossible to create a custom message for each of these errors, I am thinking to output just a wildcard error message such as `Unexpected error has been encountered. Please contact developer team."
3. But also, this wildcard error message does not seem so informative for both the developers and the users as well.

I am not sure how to properly handle exceptions and response it to the API client as informative as possible.

Comment: The error sounds like you missed a migration.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention, this error was intentional. I intentionally made this so that I get an exception. What I'm trying to solve is to know how to properly handle exception so that it doesn't return that whole error in the API response message.

Comment: I don't think I need to output that whole thing as it contains the actual DB query and columns, and it doesn't look professional. I am thinking maybe I could tell it to return "Column unifiedid does not exist." This way user knows exactly what happened.

Comment: But again, there can be tons of errors and it would be impossible to create a custom message for these errors. So instead, I'm thinking maybe I can just send a wildcard error message like "Unexpected error occurred." But for me, this does not seem so informative. Is this enough though? Or is there a better way to handle errors to return a much more informative error message?

Comment: Usually, no 'client' is interested in detailed database errors. Since they are not talking directly to the database, there is nothing a client can do.